# How do I show random question without repetition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click the button my website stucks I dont know what is happening. I am using the while loop to not repeat the question in my quiz app. Help will be appreciated. The App and Questions function components are listed below. I am bringing my questions from an object array.

**App.js**

```
'''

import "./App.css";
import Questions from "./layout/Questions";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Questions />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


'''
```

**Questions.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import mcqs from "../data/mcqs";

const Questions = () => {
const handleButtonClick = () => {
 setquestionCounter(questionCounter + 1);
};
let randomQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * mcqs.length);
let [questionCounter, setquestionCounter] = useState(1);

if (questionCounter <= mcqs.length) {
 while (mcqs[randomQuestion].question === "999") {
   randomQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * mcqs.length);
 }
}
const string = mcqs[randomQuestion].question;
mcqs[randomQuestion].question = "999";
return (
 questionCounter <= mcqs.length && (
   <div className="questions">
     Q{questionCounter}:{string}
     <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Next Question</button>
   </div>
 )
);
};

export default Questions;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be triggering the infinite loop. By the way, doing the guesswork until getting the item that was not previously shown is not a good idea. You'd be much better off splicing the array of questions to show upon each iteration until it's empty:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const questions = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5']

const Question = ({question, pickQuestion}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{question}</div>
      <button onClick={pickQuestion}>Next Question</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(),
        [questionsToShow, setQuestionsToShow] = useState(questions),
        nextQuestion = () => {
          const questionsToShowCopy = [...questionsToShow],
                nextQuestionIdx = 0|Math.random()*questionsToShowCopy.length
          setCurrentQuestion(questionsToShowCopy.splice(nextQuestionIdx,1))
          setQuestionsToShow(questionsToShowCopy)
        }
        
  useEffect(nextQuestion, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Question 
        question={currentQuestion} 
        pickQuestion={nextQuestion} 
      />
    </div>
  )
}

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```